# Как сделать суммирование вводимых в HashMap значений Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-hashmap

У меня есть список с объектами, содержащими LocaleDateTime и int.
Я хочу раскидать значения по ключам в цикле, не проверяя, есть ли в Map такой ключ. Если нет, то он создаётся с переданным значением, а если есть, то к предыдущему значению по этому ключу прибавляется новое. Каким методом можно реализовать такое?

Сейчас код выглядит вот так:

```
Map<LocalDate, Integer> caloriesPerDate = new HashMap<>();
        for (UserMeal userMeal : meals) {
            LocalDate key = LocalDate.from(userMeal.getDateTime());
            int calories = userMeal.getCalories();

            if (caloriesPerDate.containsKey(key)) caloriesPerDate.put(key, caloriesPerDate.get(key) + calories);
            else caloriesPerDate.put(key, calories);
        }
```

Хотелось бы сократить его и сделать более изящным.

Comment: можете привести пример List и Map?

Comment: Map<LocalDate, Integer> caloriesPerDate и List<UserMeal> meals. Объект UserMeal содержит LocalDateTime и int calories.

Comment: Я нашёл метод computeIfAbsent, но пока не очень понимаю, как его использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте метод merge. Для вашего примера можно написать так:

```
Map<LocalDate, Integer> caloriesPerDate = new HashMap<>();
meals.forEach(m ->
    caloriesPerDate.merge(m.date.toLocalDate(), m.calories, (value, newValue) -> value + newValue)
);
```

Comment: Интересный вариант. Правда я где-то видел такое выражение: (key, Integer::sum). Единственная проблема- найти метод не могу. Но это вряд ли был merge.

Comment: Собственно, вы правильно написали, так будет ещё короче.

meals.forEach(m ->
            caloriesPerDate.merge(m.date.toLocalDate(), m.calories, Integer::sum)
        );

Comment: Спасибо, да, так и есть. Только LocalDate.from(userMeal.getDateTime())

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать через Stream API, например:

```
Map<LocalDate, Integer> caloriesPerDate = meals.stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(UserMeal::getDateTime, UserMeal::getCalories, Integer::sum)
            );
```

UPD:

```
Map<LocalDate, Integer> caloriesPerDate = meals.stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(meal -> meal.getDateTime.toLocalDate(), UserMeal::getCalories, Integer::sum)
            );
```

Comment: А как одновременно преобразовать UserMeal::getDateTime в LocaleDate?

Comment: Обновил код с учетом преобразования в LocaleDate.